# Convert datetime ns to daily format

Tags: python, datetime, converters

I have a column in my dataframe in this formate:

2013-01-25 00:00:00+00:00

non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]

I would like to convert this to daily format, like this:

2013-01-25

I tried this approach, but have been receiving an error:

```
df['date_column'].date()
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'

The error message is not quite clear to me, because the object should be a datetime object according to df.info()

Can anyone suggest an approach of how to do this?

Comment: You can format this with `pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'])`.

Comment: But I still get the same error message, I believe it is already a datetime object.

Comment: `pd` is here the `pandas` module, *not* the dataframe. I tested this locally and that works.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But when I do this, I get the same error message: pd.to_datetime(pipeline_output['date_column']).date()

Comment: but you should drop the `.date()` at the end.

Comment: But how do I convert this to a date then, I need to drop the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: It is not advisable to convert to `date` objects, since then you lose a lot of functionality to inspect the `date`s. It might be better to just [**`dt.floor(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), or [**`dt.normalize(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html).

You can convert a series of strings with [**`pd.to_datetime(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), for example:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2013-01-25 00:00:00+00:00']))
0   2013-01-25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

We can then later convert this to `date` objects with [**`.dt.date`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2013-01-25 00:00:00+00:00'])).dt.date
0    2013-01-25
dtype: object
```

Note that a `date` is *not* a native Numpy type, and thus it will use a Python `date(..)` object. A disadvantage of this is that you can no longer process the objects are datetime-like objects. So the `Series` more or less loses a lot of functionality.

It might be better to just [**`dt.floor(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) to the day, and thus keep it a `datetime64[ns]` object:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2013-01-25 00:00:00+00:00'])).dt.floor(freq='d')
0   2013-01-25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

We can use [**`dt.normalize(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) as well. This just sets the time component to `0:00:00`, and leaves the timezone unaffected:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2013-01-25 00:00:00+00:00'])).dt.normalize()
0   2013-01-25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the detailed explanation. So this works: dt.date but the dt.floor for some reason does not convert it correctly (it remains in the same format)

Comment: @Tartaglia: and `.normalize()`. Did you use `freq='d'`?

Comment: Had a typo in there, now it works. Perfect, thank you so much for your help!!